# background attachment not working

Tags: html, css

I want to make a parallax scrolling but background-attachment is not working for me:(
The bgcolor is actually #83b2d9. Is there even a way that I can use background-color instead of background-image for this?

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body, html {
 margin: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
 height: 100%;
}

#mainpage {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-image: url(img/bgcolor.png);
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<title>untitled</title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="mainpage">
</div>
<div id="subpage">
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus similique iure fuga, repellendus quaerat nobis illo libero! Consequatur perspiciatis cupiditate cum culpa ut impedit earum ullam velit hic. Illum, ullam? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime labore molestias totam voluptatum, deleniti culpa unde, reiciendis similique ab esse fuga minima aspernatur eius! Ad, rem et deleniti Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum odio facilis, consectetur iusto quas quaerat impedit minima aliquid quis quibusdam laudantium illo totam sint eaque atque culpa optio perferendis magnam?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis, eius! Sapiente tempora quia, ullam deleniti, ea consectetur, sequi amet numquam accusamus ex hic praesentium, enim corporis similique ut. Repudiandae, delectus!officia facere!</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you simply want to use color rather than image?

Comment: just you background-color:#83b2d9; Instead of background-image:

Comment: Take a background-color: #code

Comment: shouldn't the png url be enclosed in single quotation marks? `'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `linear-gradient` to create the needed color and you will still have a background-image and you can apply background-attachement:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
}

#mainpage {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #83b2d9, #83b2d9);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size:100% 50%;
  background-position:0 50%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainpage">
</div>
<div id="subpage">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus similique iure fuga, repellendus quaerat nobis illo libero! Consequatur perspiciatis cupiditate cum culpa ut impedit earum ullam velit hic. Illum, ullam? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
    adipisicing elit. Maxime labore molestias totam voluptatum, deleniti culpa unde, reiciendis similique ab esse fuga minima aspernatur eius! Ad, rem et deleniti Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum odio facilis, consectetur
    iusto quas quaerat impedit minima aliquid quis quibusdam laudantium illo totam sint eaque atque culpa optio perferendis magnam?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis, eius! Sapiente tempora quia, ullam deleniti, ea consectetur,
    sequi amet numquam accusamus ex hic praesentium, enim corporis similique ut. Repudiandae, delectus!officia facere!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus similique iure fuga, repellendus quaerat nobis illo libero! Consequatur perspiciatis cupiditate cum culpa ut impedit earum ullam velit hic. Illum, ullam? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
    adipisicing elit. Maxime labore molestias totam voluptatum, deleniti culpa unde, reiciendis similique ab esse fuga minima aspernatur eius! Ad, rem et deleniti Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum odio facilis, consectetur
    iusto quas quaerat impedit minima aliquid quis quibusdam laudantium illo totam sint eaque atque culpa optio perferendis magnam?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis, eius! Sapiente tempora quia, ullam deleniti, ea consectetur,
    sequi amet numquam accusamus ex hic praesentium, enim corporis similique ut. Repudiandae, delectus!officia facere!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus similique iure fuga, repellendus quaerat nobis illo libero! Consequatur perspiciatis cupiditate cum culpa ut impedit earum ullam velit hic. Illum, ullam? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
    adipisicing elit. Maxime labore molestias totam voluptatum, deleniti culpa unde, reiciendis similique ab esse fuga minima aspernatur eius! Ad, rem et deleniti Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum odio facilis, consectetur
    iusto quas quaerat impedit minima aliquid quis quibusdam laudantium illo totam sint eaque atque culpa optio perferendis magnam?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis, eius! Sapiente tempora quia, ullam deleniti, ea consectetur,
    sequi amet numquam accusamus ex hic praesentium, enim corporis similique ut. Repudiandae, delectus!officia facere!</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body, html {
 margin: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
 height: 100%;
}

#mainpage {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
background-color:#83b2d9;
 
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-size: cover;
  display:block
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<title>untitled</title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="mainpage">
</div>
<div id="subpage">
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus similique iure fuga, repellendus quaerat nobis illo libero! Consequatur perspiciatis cupiditate cum culpa ut impedit earum ullam velit hic. Illum, ullam? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime labore molestias totam voluptatum, deleniti culpa unde, reiciendis similique ab esse fuga minima aspernatur eius! Ad, rem et deleniti Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum odio facilis, consectetur iusto quas quaerat impedit minima aliquid quis quibusdam laudantium illo totam sint eaque atque culpa optio perferendis magnam?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis, eius! Sapiente tempora quia, ullam deleniti, ea consectetur, sequi amet numquam accusamus ex hic praesentium, enim corporis similique ut. Repudiandae, delectus!officia facere!</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
**CSS**

    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    body, html {
        margin: 0;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        height: 100%;
    }
    #mainpage {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        /* background-image: url(img/bgcolor.png); */
        background-color: #83b2d9;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-size: cover;
    }

**HTML**

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>untitled</title>
    <title>untitled</title>
    </head>
    </head>

    <body>

    <body>
    <div id="mainpage">
    <div id="mainpage">
    <div id="subpage">
    <div id="subpage">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus similique iure fuga, repellendus quaerat nobis illo libero! Consequatur perspiciatis cupiditate cum culpa ut impedit earum ullam velit hic. Illum, ullam? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime labore molestias totam voluptatum, deleniti culpa unde, reiciendis similique ab esse fuga minima aspernatur eius! Ad, rem et deleniti Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum odio facilis, consectetur iusto quas quaerat impedit minima aliquid quis quibusdam laudantium illo totam sint eaque atque culpa optio perferendis magnam?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis, eius! Sapiente tempora quia, ullam deleniti, ea consectetur, sequi amet numquam accusamus ex hic praesentium, enim corporis similique ut. Repudiandae, delectus!officia facere!</p>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus similique iure fuga, repellendus quaerat nobis illo libero! Consequatur perspiciatis cupiditate cum culpa ut impedit earum ullam velit hic. Illum, ullam? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime labore molestias totam voluptatum, deleniti culpa unde, reiciendis similique ab esse fuga minima aspernatur eius! Ad, rem et deleniti Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum odio facilis, consectetur iusto quas quaerat impedit minima aliquid quis quibusdam laudantium illo totam sint eaque atque culpa optio perferendis magnam?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis, eius! Sapiente tempora quia, ullam deleniti, ea consectetur, sequi amet numquam accusamus ex hic praesentium, enim corporis similique ut. Repudiandae, delectus!officia facere!</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>

    </body>
    </html>
    </html>
```